# Can't enforce https for github pages with default domain

Tags: github, https, github-pages

I tried to deploy the site of a github repository from the associated `gh-pages` branch, using the default domain.

I've already done it many times but I never encountered the case where the checkbox "Enforce HTTPS" could not be checked (actually, I could not uncheck it usually). However, this is required to deploy the site.

[image]

It has been over two hours since I choose `gh-pages` branch as source. So I hold out little hope that it was just a matter of time.

Is there something I forgot to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although my `gh-pages` branch was fully functional, I needed to push again after I had selected `gh-pages` branch as the source of my site. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is your assets (js scripts, css files, etc) all in https://?

(https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https#examples-of-assets-referenced-in-an-html-file)

Comment: The only locations where I could fild `http://` and not `https://` are in `xmlns` attributes and links like this `<a href="http://fsf.org/" class="uri">http://fsf.org/</a>`. But I checked and I also found them in already deployed sites.